# login post error

Tags: php, html, xml

I am looking for a method to check whether a user has entered something into a login script or not.  I have tried 
`if (!empty($_POST))` 
but this method failed.  As I am new to php I am not sure as to what other clean method to use.

```
<?php
    if ( !empty($post)){
    header("Location:login.php");
    echo"Invalid Username or Password";
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Administrator Login Page</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            @import "style.css";
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Administrator Login Page</h1>
        </br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
        <form action="admin_verify.php" method="post">
            User Name:
            <input type="text" name="admin_name" />
            </br></br>
            Password:&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="password" name="admin_password" />
            </br></br>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
            <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of simply checking if the form is filled, you may wish to check the username and password on this page as well. If you wish to leave that to `login.php`, save the contents in `$_POST` into `$_SESSION`.

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)){
    if (strlen($_POST["admin_name"]) > 0 && strlen($_POST["admin_password"]) > 0) {
        header("Location:login.php");
        exit;
    } else {
        $not_filled = true;
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Administrator Login Page</title>
<style type="text/css">
@import "style.css";
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Administrator Login Page</h1>
</br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
<?php if ($not_filled) echo"Invalid Username or Password"; ?>
<form action="admin_verify.php" method="post">
User Name: <input type="text" name="admin_name" />
</br></br>
Password:&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="password" name="admin_password" />
</br></br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
    <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should put this code in `admin_verify.php` not in `login.php`

```
<?php
    if ( !empty($post)){
        header("Location:login.php");
        exit;        
    }
?>
```

Better you should check all fields entered or not by

```
if( !isset($_POST['admin_name'], $_POST['admin_password'] )) {
     header("Location:login.php");
     exit; 
}
```

if you want to send some message back to login page, you can send that in get parameter or use sessions

```
header("Location:login.php?msg=Invalid Username or Password");
exit;
```

Comment: Thank you Venu I'll check this out today I like the message section will implement that for sure

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if((isset($_POST['admin_name']) && isset($_POST['admin_password']))
{
   //INSTRUCTION
}
```

Comment: Can be simplified to: isset(first, second). That is, isset accepts a variable about of arguments.